# How to add svn external to github repository

Tags: svn, github, tortoisesvn

Can't commit `svn` external to `github` repository, server response is:

> **Error:** Invalid PROPPATCH property.

Answer (score 2):

Github doesn't support svn:externals,  https://help.github.com/articles/subversion-properties-supported-by-github/ .